# Zoom issue on mobile device though that works fine on desktop

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

My front-end works with bootrstrap3.

Firstable I had responsive issues on mobile device that I fixed by adding the meta below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

That works well but I have still a strange issue. Most of times, by landing on a page on mobile device, the zoom is lower than 100%.

Actually, what I note is that when the issue is happening, the whole page is displayed on the viewport, so that the zoom is adapted to the total height and width of the page.

If anyone has a solution to fix this issue that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your head-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

For Mobile Safari in iOS 4.2.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

*We are disabling zoom on a mobile web based application. You can't zoom in Native iOS apps and it's not required in our web application. If your site or app is mobile optimised then your users won't need to zoom. There are always use cases for disabling zoom. It doesn't have to always be one way or the other*.